# Scheduling queries in google big query not working (kept scheduled but not running)

Tags: google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks

I am working with big query (quite new with this tool actually). I made a query that runs properly (even in a view). But when i schedule it, so it can run every day, it simple doesn't run. As i show in the image below, it simple keeps as programmed but never actually run. I don't know what else to do, i try changing all the possible settings in the scheduler, but still doesnt work. Anybody knows what could be happening here?

Thanks!

[Screenshot to show how the queries all always scheduled and never run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tW3B.png)

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the BigQuery Stackdriver logs so we can better understand the root cause of your issue. Also, have you checked if the destination table is indeed empty? Have you checked the documentation on how to set up a scheduled query? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries